# Cocoapods error - 49 errors when installing GooglePlacesAutocomplete

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-places-api

I included Google places in my Podfile like so:

pod 'GooglePlacesAutocomplete', then I ran pod install and that worked. Then, I was getting an error on my
"import GooglePlacesAutocomplete" so I went to product -> Edit Scheme -> Build and added the new framework. This didn't work and now I am getting errors in nearly every file of my project from the GooglePlacesAutocomplete:
[image]

I know this has got to be a small fix, does anyone know what it is?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did Some quick research and the Autocomplete API seems to be under

```
pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

Refer to [Get Started with the Places API for iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) and to [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete)

Comment: Thank you, this must be the new version. The old one was for Swift 2

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

Add the following pods

```
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

For implementing autocomplete :
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

```
import GooglePlaces
```

Comment: Ok, so this is deprecated? https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete

Comment: The repo is 5 years old. Those APIs likely have been deprecated. :)
The links on the repo point to the above APIs. (Check Readme bottom)

Comment: Maybe this can help:
https://github.com/shmidt/GooglePlacesSearchController

Comment: @Ryan, the framework you are referencing is not the original Google autocomplete and hence not up to date... it was last updated 4 years ago which is decades in tech years

Comment: Thank you both very much. When dealing with Cocoa pods getting errors, you never know if its some problem with builds or some form of "reset content and settings" and just cleaning everything. At least I know where to look now, thanks!